# Is there a way to have panel.grid.major in theme under specific angle in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization

I am wondering if there is a way to rotate panel.grid.major.x lines under specific angle in ggplot2? I've seen in the documentation that it uses [element_line](http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.3.1/element_line.htm)  but it does not have an `angle` parameter which corresponds to the rotation in axis.title.x-like functions in the `theme` element of the `ggplot` object from `ggplot2` package from `R`?

**EDIT**

I would like to have additional lines on the plot (as in the attached example below) but instead of adding `geom_abline` for each line I thought it would be easier to rotate the panel grid.
[image]

Comment: Could [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33396922/1305688) answer possible help you obtain what you are looking for?

Comment: Nope :p it does rotate whole ggplot

Comment: I'm curious to what you are trying to achieve by rotating the major grid. If it's possible maybe you could describe it and add the `[data-visualization]' tag?

Comment: @EricFail I've editedmy question with an example :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's definitely going to be much much easier to use `geom_abline` than to try to change the way gridlines work with coordinates.  You don't need one `geom_abline` for each line, it takes vectors as slope and intercept.  So:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = disp, y = mpg)) +
  geom_point() +
  theme_void() +
  geom_abline(slope = 2, intercept = 0:10 * 50 - 800, colour = "grey50")
```

[image]

Comment: Oh, geom_abline is vectorized.. By the way, theme void is cool :) thanks for the reply