# Rotate entire ggplot() without rotating any text R

Tags: r, ggplot2, rotation

I am looking to rotate the entire plot, axis and all, but keeping the axis labels and title how they are so they can be read horizontally.

```
library(ggplot2)
data(mtcars)

ggplot() + geom_point(data=mtcars,aes(x=mpg,y=cyl)) + 
  labs(title = "MPG vs Cylinders",
       x = "", y = "") + 
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size=40),axis.text.x=element_text(size=35),axis.text.y=element_text(size=35))
```

So the plot that this code generated would ideally be rotated 30 degrees or so counter-clockwise like so:
[image]

But the title should still be displayed horizontal, instead of with a 30 degree turn. Same with the axis labels (I put the plot in MS word and rotated it with the little green circle). Any thoughts? Is it even possible?

Comment: You can set `angle = -30` in your `element_text` theming to account for the rotation, but I don't know how to rotate the plot.

Comment: I also don't know how to rotate the plot. If it's a one-time thing, it might be quickest to rotate the text as @Gregor says, and then rotate the plot in other software.

Comment: As a side note, inheritance is built-in to ggplot theming, so rather than setting `axis.text.x` and `axis.text.y` to the same thing, you can just set `axis.text`; both `x` and `y` axes will inherit the setting.

Comment: Thanks for that Gregor.

Comment: if you paste it into MS word as a metafile (in Rstudio, export, copy to clipboard, click metafile) you can ungroup it (right click, group, ungroup) then select everythat isn't text and rotate.

Comment: You can do it with `p <- plot1 + theme(text = element_text(angle=-30))` to rotate the text to compensate, then `print(p, vp=viewport(angle=30))` to rotate the whole plot, but the clipping is a bit weird (cuts off axes but not points).

Comment: jeremycg, that could be an extra step to further tweak some aspects, but it seems difficult (for me, anyway) because you have to select every grid line and point. Good thought though. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Would this work for you (code below)

[image: dd]

```
# install.packages("ggplot2", dependencies = TRUE)
library(ggplot2)

rotation <- 30

p <- ggplot() + geom_point(data=mtcars,aes(x=mpg,y=cyl)) + labs(title = "MPG vs Cylinders", x = "", y = "") + theme(plot.title = element_text(size=20), axis.text.x=element_text(size=15),axis.text.y=element_text(size=15)) + theme(text = element_text(angle=(-1*rotation))) 

# install.packages("grid", dependencies = TRUE)
library(grid)
print(p, vp=viewport(angle=rotation,  width = unit(.75, "npc"), height = unit(.75, "npc")))
```

Comment: That output is really similar to what Derwin McGeary suggested in the first post comments. It's close, but the weird clipping is something I'd ideally like to avoid. It looks like the `plot.margin()` in Roland's answer solves that.

Comment: That's neat as well... When I run your code, I get way different aspect ratios that in your picture, but it does produce the same plot as Roland's suggestion as far as I can tell.

Comment: I guess the "safest" way is to plot to a PDF e.g. `pdf("file_file.pdf")` and then your plot code `dev.off` see [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/grDevices/html/pdf.html) for more.

Answer (score 3):

This gives some warnings, but works:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)

data(mtcars)
grid.newpage()
pushViewport(viewport(angle = -30))
grid.draw(ggplotGrob(
  ggplot() + geom_point(data = mtcars,aes(x = mpg,y = cyl)) +
    labs(title = "MPG vs Cylinders",
         x = "", y = "") +
    theme(text = element_text(angle = 30),
          plot.margin = unit(c(0.07, 0.08, 0.2, 0.04), "npc"))
))
```

[image: resulting plot]

Fine tune as needed.